# Regex in Python to match all the files in a folder

Tags: python, regex, path

I'm very bad at regex. 
I'm trying to locate files in a folder based on the file names. Most of the filenames are in the format `GSE1234_series_matrix.txt`, hence I've been using `os.path.join("files", GSE_num + "_series_matrix.txt")`. However, a few files have names like `GSE1234-GPL22_series_matrix.txt`. I'm not sure how to address all the files starting with a GSE number and ending with _series_matrix.txt together, possibly in one statement. I'd really appreciate any help.

EDIT - I have these series matrix text files in a folder, for which I mention the path using path join. I also input a text file, which has all the GSE numbers. This way it runs the script only for selected GSE numbers. So not everything that's in the folder is in GSE num list AND the list just has GSE numbers and not GPL. For instance the file GSE1234-GPL22_series_matrix.txt would be GSE1234 in the list.

Answer (score 6):

Skip using regexes entirely.

```
good_filenames = [name for name in filenames if name.startswith("GSE") and name.endswith("_series_matrix.txt")]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a question. This gives me a list. I need individual file names or in other words, how can I incorporate it into the os.path.join statement?

Comment: I guess you could do `good_filenames = [os.path.join("files", name) for name in filenames if name.startswith("GSE") and name.endswith("_series_matrix.txt")]`. I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: It gives me `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

Comment: `filenames` needs to be a list of strings, e.g. the kind returned by `os.listdir`. Not sure if my answer made that clear.

Comment: I have one last question. I just realized that I didn't frame my question properly. I have these series matrix text files in a folder, for which I mention the path using path join. I also input a text file, which has all the GSE numbers. This way it runs the script only for selected GSE numbers. So not everything that's in the folder is in GSE num list AND the list just has GSE numbers and not GPL. For instance the file GSE1234-GPL22_series_matrix.txt would be GSE1234 in the list.

Answer (score 4):

You could use glob. Depending on how much of the path you include in the pattern, you wouldn't have to worry about using `os.path.join` at all.

```
import glob
good_filenames = glob.glob('/your/path/here/GSE*_series_matrix.txt')
```

returns:

```
['/your/path/here/GSE1234_series_matrix.txt',
 '/your/path/here/GSE1234-GPL22_series_matrix.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's answer is great! If you'd like to use a regex, you can do something like this:

```
^GSE\d+.*series_matrix.txt$
```

That would match anything that starts with GSE and a number, and ends with series_matrix.txt

Comment: Should I use re.findall? I don't understand how I can use it in the path join statement

Comment: Use re.match to identify the names you want, i.e. [os.path.join("files", name) for name in filenames if re.match(r"GSE\d+.*series_matrix\.txt$", name)].

Comment: Maybe you'd like to list all the files in the directory with `os.listdir`. This is similar to what Kevin suggested:

    `for i in os.listdir("./files"):`
      `re.search('^GSE\d+.*series_matrix.txt$',i)`
`